# Argument Exception in Dictionary Getter

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, clr, solidworks

I have run into a weird situation where using the getter on a C# dictionary in a specific way yields an argument exception even though that should [never happen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The issue seems to only happen my computer.

Actually I have already found an alternate working solution to my original problem. However i would really like to undestand the why original solution does not work.

I have dictionary that is used in an Addin for Solidworks. It tracks open documents and their eventhandlers. It is define like this:

```
private Dictionary<ModelDoc2, DocumentEventHandler> _openDocs = new Dictionary<ModelDoc2, DocumentEventHandler>();
```

Solidworks has [method](http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~activedoc.html) to retrieve the active document. When i attempt to use it to retrive the eventhandler for the active document like this:

```
_openDocs[SwApp.ActiveDoc]
```

i get this ArgumentException:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Method 'SWAddIn.DocumentEventHandler 
get_Item(SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2)' declared on type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2,SWAddIn.DocumentEventHandler]' cannot be called with instance of type
'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2,SWAddIn.DocumentEventHandler]''
```

The alternative solution i found was to simply bind the active doc to a variable first like so:

```
ModelDoc2 activedoc = SwApp.ActiveDoc;
_openDocs[activedoc]
```

If anyone could help me understand that would be great!

Some extra info:

According to the documentation "ActiveDoc" is supposed to return an "object" but intellisense tells me it is a dynamic

As mentioned, it only happens on my machine, so i am guessing it is environmental in some way

The snippet of code that doesn't work is directly out of Solidworks' example files.

ModelDoc2 is defined in an assembly called SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks with this definition:

```
[CoClass(typeof(ModelDoc2Class))]
[Guid("B90793FB-EF3D-4B80-A5C4-99959CDB6CEB")]
public interface ModelDoc2 : IModelDoc2
```

Here is the stacktrace from the excpetion if that is of interest:

```
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateCallInstanceType(Type instanceType, MethodInfo method)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateAccessor(Expression instance, MethodInfo method, ParameterInfo[] indexes, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateIndexedProperty(Expression instance, PropertyInfo property, ReadOnlyCollection`1& argList)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(Expression instance, PropertyInfo indexer, IEnumerable`1 arguments)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.GenerateProperty(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Visit(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.GenerateLambda(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Visit(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.Rewrite(TypeManager typeManager, EXPR pExpr, IEnumerable`1 listOfParameters)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.CreateExpressionTreeFromResult(IEnumerable`1 parameters, ArgumentObject[] arguments, Scope pScope, EXPR pResult)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, DynamicMetaObject& deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpGetIndexBinder.FallbackGetIndex(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore[T](CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
   at CortimeSWAddIn.SwAddin.OnPostDocChange() in C:\Users\asdf\Development\SWAdd\SWAddIn\SWAddIn\SwAddin.cs:line 1065
```

Comment: This is unexpected. It should work if the COM object is implemented correctly. The error you have is strange it tells us your giving an instance of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2[SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2,SWAddIn.DocumentEventHandler]` to the method. Are you sure the code you show us is the real code with error? (I don't have SW to test)

Comment: Fairly sure. Where else could it be? The entire line of code where the exception happened is a check to see whether the document had finished loading: `if(_openDocs[SwApp.ActiveDoc].Loaded)`. `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary\`2[SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2,SWAddIn.DocumentEventHandler]` is the type of the dictionary.  My guess was that this error message was due to the method being implement as an extension. and thus have it as it's first argument (if that makes any sense).

Comment: This exception is strange because the type is the same. What extension method are you talking about? Can we have the real piece of code?

Comment: `if(_openDocs[SwApp.ActiveDoc].Loaded)` IS the real piece of code.  There is not much context either. The only thing preceding it is a check to see if the active doc is null

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I've seen an exception that says you can't use an instance of type X as type X, this has indicated that I have multiple versions of type X loaded into memory side by side.

Run your program and look at the Modules window and see if there is more than one version of your SolidWorks library loaded. If there is, then that's your problem. One part of your code resolved type X to version A, and the other part of your code that's expecting instances of type X is expecting version B.

You can usually solve it by updating everything to point to the same version of the library or by using [assembly binding redirects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions) in your App.config.

Comment: Weirdly almost none of the expected dll's show up in the modules list. We include these 7 reference from solidoworks:
SolidWorks.Interop.cosworks, SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks,SolidWorks.Interop.swcommands, SolidWorks.Interop.swconst, SolidWorks.Interop.swmotionstudy, SolidWorks.Interop.swpublished and solidworkstools. But only the last one shows up in the modules list. The doc type it self should be in SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks

Comment: I just had a thought. We may be using the Interop assemblies only to build against and then Solidworks Redirects it to another assembly. Does that sound right? Is there a way to find out what assembly it is redirected to?

Comment: This answer is completely reasonable. This is just like overloading. That is if the compiler doesn't know what is the type of the input, it cannot decide which _openDocs must be used

Comment: @Taus the Modules window should show you exactly which version of the library is loaded into memory and where it loaded it from.

Comment: I find it very strange that i don't see them in the module list then. There are other Solidworks related dll's, but not the ones i linked with

Comment: @Taus The one(s) you're concerned with are the one(s) that define classes named ModelDoc2. It could be defined in multiple assemblies.

Comment: That would be SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.  At least that is were i am taken when i use "Go To definition". I edited the post with its definition

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting it, it would appear that it isn't returning the correct type.  Once you declare the variable, it is resolving and casting properly.

```
_openDocs[(ModelDoc2)SwApp.ActiveDoc]
```

Comment: As mentioned i already found the solution which is pretty much this. I just assign it to a variable.

However i am trying to understand why it didn't work in the first place. I would think that dictionaries should be able to resolve the type or at least warn at compile time that it is ambiguous/